# What is the syntax to use List.AddRange with an F# list?

Tags: f#

Let's say I have:

```
let mutableList = List<string>()
let someList    = [ "a"; "b"; "c" ]
```

how can I do something like this:

```
mutableList.AddRange(someList)
```

I have a case when I need to add elements to a list based on some dynamic criteria and the elements arrive as lists.
I understand I can iterate through my list and add them one by one, but I'm curious if there is a quick / clean syntax to make the immutable lists work with AddRange?

Comment: You can combine two lists with `@`.

Comment: Oh wait. What you wrote you can actually "just do", You can give an F# list to a BCL `List<_>.AddRange`, it takes an enumerable. So `mutableList.AddRange(someList)` is fine. (edit, seeing the just posted answer, I realize I may not have understood your question correctly).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly. The code using `AddRange` in your snippet works fine (if you open the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace).

I would probably use `ResizeList<string>` rather than `List<string>`, but this is just using an F# alias for the type name, which is easier to understand and does not require an extra namespace.

If you are asking how to construct an immutable list in a way that is a bit like using `AddRange`, then my recommendation would be to look at list comprehensions.

Let's say we have the following (completely meaningless) code using a mutable list:

```
let l = ResizeArray<string>()
for x in 0 .. 10 do 
  if x % 7 = 0 then 
    l.AddRange(["hey"; string x])
```

To do the same thing using an immutable list, you can write:

```
let l =
  [ for x in 0 .. 10 do 
      if x % 7 = 0 then 
        yield! ["hey"; string x] ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't add a range directly on an immutable list. By definition that list can't be changed. But you can create a new immutable list out of two other lists.

You can use the [List.append](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/lists#operating-on-multiple-lists) method.

```
let goodol'list = []
let extendedList = List.append goodol'list [ "a"; "b"; "c" ]
```

Another way as [Abel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/111575/abel) pointed out in the comments, is to use the @ shorthand.

```
let goodol'list = []
let extendedList = goodol'list @ [ "a"; "b"; "c" ]
```

As to how to dynamically add items to an immutable list you can use [Tomas Petricek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33518/tomas-petricek) provided answer.